# Showing existence of a unique extremal

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

In a set of practice problems I was asked this:

If $\gamma - \beta \geq -\frac{1}{4}$ then for any $A,B$ $\exists!$ extremal for

$\inf\{\int^b_a x^2y'^2+2\beta x yy' + \gamma x^2\}$

I am trying to solve this issue, so i took the first obvious step and computed the E-L equation getting:

$$2x^2y'' + 4xy' + 2(\beta - \gamma)y = 0$$

At this point I am already screwed because I don't know how to solve a second order ODE with non linear coefficients.

I decided to pretend the coefficients were constant and calculate the root of the associated polynomial.

This didn't give me something useful and I don't think it's the correct approach anyway.

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: That's an Euler equation.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: It is not clear what $\gamma$ has to do with the above as it just contributes $\int_a^b \gamma x^2 dx$ regardless of $y$.

Comment: @copper.hat it's how the question is worded and I assume it's encessary to satisfy the condition. I am looking into the euler equation.

Comment: @Bruce that was essentially the answer btw